# Finding imaginary part of an expression

Tags: complex

How can I find the Imaginary part of an expression by knowing that all parameters are real?

```
exp= I n + (a+d+I c)/((f+b)+Sqrt[uy-gh])
```

The answer should be

```
 n+c/((f+b)+Sqrt[uy-gh])
```

Comment: Have you tried `Im[expr]`?

Comment: Yes, it returns lots of complicated arguments. I need to use the information that all parameters are real to make the anwer better@YashGandhi

Comment: Can you add some more information here? This doesn't really help. May be an example?

Comment: I added it @YashGandhi

Comment: Well at least you need to type the imaginary unit correctly, it should be `I n` or `I*n` instead of `in`

Comment: It is not my code, it is an example. BTW, could you help please?@happyfish

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
ComplexExpand@Im[exp /. Sqrt[-gh + uy] -> X] /. X -> Sqrt[-gh + uy]
```

`ComplexExpand` assumes all unknown symbols are real. Hence by replacing the square root by an a single variable you get your desired result (which is only correct if the square root is real!). Alternatively, you could do

```
Simplify[ComplexExpand@Im@exp, uy>gh]
```

but that produces a more messy (but correct) result.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** This works as expected:

```
In[610]:= exp = I n + (a + d + I c)/((f + b) + Sqrt[u y - g h]);

In[635]:= Simplify[Im[exp], Element[Variables[exp], Reals] && (b + f != -Sqrt[u y - g h]) && (u y >= g h)]
Out[635]= n + c/(b + f + Sqrt[-g h + u y])
```

**Original:** Assuming all your variables are reals, Here is what you get:

```
In[610]:= exp = I n + (a + d + I c)/((f + b) + Sqrt[u y - g h]);

In[611]:= Simplify[Im[exp], Element[Variables[exp], Reals]] 
Out[611]= n + Im[(a + I c + d)/(b + f + Sqrt[-g h + u y])]
```

The problem here is with the signs of u,v,g,h. As Mathematica doesn't know what they are, it gives you a result in Mathematica expressions. However, if you just change the sign of the expression in square root, you get an expected result:

```
In[607]:= exp = I n + (a + d + I c)/((f + b) + Sqrt[u y + g h]);

In[608]:= Simplify[Im[exp], Element[Variables[exp], Reals]] 
Out[608]= n + Im[(a + I c + d)/(b + f + Sqrt[g h + u y])]

In[609]:= Simplify[Im[exp], And @@ (# > 0 & /@ Variables[exp])]
Out[609]= n + c/(b + f + Sqrt[g h + u y])
```